# How to add an arbitrary line to the zsh history instead of the running command? (imitate bash's `history -s`)?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, history

In Bash, I can use `history -s` to append a line to the history list. When I do this, the command itself does not get saved in history.

```sh
$ history -s "another command"
$ history 
# ...
# 100 another command
```

In Zsh, `print -s` achieves something similar, but with an exception.

```sh
$ print -s "another command"
$ history
# ...
#  99 print -s "another command"
# 100 another command
```

As it can be seen above, the `print` command itself is also saved in the history list. Is there a way to prevent this and simulate the `history -s` command in Zsh?

Comment: A workaround is that you precede the print command with a blank. That prevents the addition to the history for any command.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to solve this in the Z Shell, all of which can be used in tandem.

## Prefix a space

Add to your `.zshrc` file

```bash
setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE
```

Then, to can cause any line to be dropped from history (once the next command line is executed or the shell is exited), prefix it with a space before running it.

See [`man zshoptions`, section "History"](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-HISTIGNORESPACE).

## Define an ignore pattern

To automatically exclude all commands matching a given pattern from being written to the history file (but still be available in the session's local history), add to your to your `.zshrc` file

```bash
HISTORY_IGNORE='<pattern>'
```

See [`man zshparam`, section "Parameters Used By The Shell"](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-HISTORY_005fIGNORE).

## Define your own ignore logic

For an even more sophisticated way to exclude lines from history, you can define in your `.zshrc` file this function

```bash
zshaddhistory() {
  ...
}
```

which receives the history line in question as argument and can return

- `0` to save the line to history,
- `1` to drop the line from history (once the next command line is executed or the shell is exited), or
- `2` to include the line in the session's local history but not write it to `$HISTFILE`.

See [`man zshmisc`, section "Special Functions"](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-zshaddhistory).

You can even define multiple such functions with arbitrary names, by adding to your to your `.zshrc` file

```bash
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
```

and then

```bash
add-zsh-hook zshaddhistory <function name>
```

for each such function.

See [`man zsh contrib`, section "Manipulating Hook Functions"](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Manipulating-Hook-Functions).